# Notification of unsupported browser in app built with create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, typescript, browser, create-react-app

I have created a web app with create-react-app. I need to notify users with older browsers (IE10 for example) that their browser is not supported and they should switch to a more recent one.

I am trapped in a catch 22, as if the browser is not supported the js bundle will trigger an error and stop running. How can I work around this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about putting something in the `index.html`?

like this: `if (/MSIE \d/.test(window.navigator.userAgent) {...}`

not tested but something like that should work and then you can post a message in there to the users

alternatively you could try: `<noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>` putting something in there.

again not entirely sure if this will work but I think the html should still display stuff, just not the JavaScript

Comment: doh I didn't think about adding code to the index.html template. Thanks, I'll try it out and report back.